# Deploying Angular Component Library to Github Pages Only absolute URLs are supported

Tags: angular

I am following a tutorial about building a Angular component Library and publishing it to Github pages.

https://dev.to/brgrz/create-a-library-with-angular-and-publish-it-to-github-package-registry-1pch

At the end, after finishing everything else when I publish my library I get an error that I do not understand.

'Only absolute URLs are supported'

This is github repo https://github.com/uweDuesing/mapStuff

Looking into the verbose error log:

```
18 verbose stack TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported
18 verbose stack     at getNodeRequestOptions (/home/uwe/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0      /lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/request.js:131:11)
18 verbose stack     at fetch.Promise (/home/uwe/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:44:21)
18 verbose stack     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
18 verbose stack     at fetch (/home/uwe/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:41:10)
18 verbose stack     at retry (/home/uwe/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/index.js:332:14)
18 verbose stack     at /home/uwe/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/promise-retry/index.js:29:24
19 verbose cwd /home/uwe/projects/mapStuff/dist/map-stuff
20 verbose Linux 5.3.0-51-generic
21 verbose argv "/home/uwe/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/bin/node" "/home/uwe/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/bin/npm" "publish"
22 verbose node v10.19.0
23 verbose npm  v6.13.4
24 error Only absolute URLs are supported
```

I am sorry for the slightly vague question - but I do not even know where to start asking the right thing!

Thanks for the help,
Uwe

Answer (score 0):

I had a very different problem with publishing, but perhaps this may help you:
1.) configure the .npmrc-File for your library
2.) use the publishConfig-Property in the package.json

Comment: Hi, would you mind giving me an example of the publishConfig property? I have a .npmrc file sitting in my home folder with the token and one .npmrc file in the library folder pointing to the github registry...

Comment: {
  "name": "...",
  "publishConfig": {
     "registry": "<link to repository>"
  }
}
Sometimes I had another problem with the .npmrc-File: the build-process didn't seem to use it. I thought of some sort of a bug, but I'm not sure. You had to rebuild it again in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

After all the problem that I faced was caused by an incorrect value in my .npmrc file in my user folder. The url to the gthub npm registry was broken

https://npm.pkg.github.com/

Really  silly of me, but this is just how the cookie crumbles sometimes.